# DKIM check=pass but DomainKeys check=neutral

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, dkim, opendkim

I got it to set up DKIM, I sent a test mail to check-*auth@verifier.port25.com* and reply was :

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

looks good, but why DomainKeys check just neutral ? in the mail-header I see the DKIM-signature, is that a big problem that its just neutral ? how to fix that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up DomainKeys](https://serverfault.com/questions/532614/setting-up-domainkeys)

Comment: Read the linked answer. You can ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

The check is neutral because DomainKeys is not DKIM. From the Wikipedia [DomainKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) article:

> DomainKeys (informally DK) is a deprecated e-mail authentication
>   system designed by Yahoo to verify the DNS domain of an e-mail sender
>   and the message integrity.
>
> Aspects of DomainKeys, along with parts of Identified Internet Mail,
>   were combined to create DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM), which is
>   now widely used.
>
> Both DomainKeys and DKIM were published in May 2007, DomainKeys as an
>   "historical" protocol, and DKIM as its standards-track replacement.

You have already "fixed" the problem by using the the newer standard, DKIM.